# Why is my own implementation of Bubble Sort so much slower than another one I found online?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, sorting

I wrote my implementation of Bubble Sort according to my understanding of the general principle of how the algorithm works, and then compared it against another implementation I found online.

```
def my_bubble_sort(n):
    switched = True
    while switched:
        switched = False
        for i in range(1, len(n)):
            if n[i] < n[i - 1]:
                switched = True
                n[i - 1], n[i] = n[i], n[i - 1]
    return n


def some_other_bubble_sort(n):
    for i in range(len(n) - 1):
        for j in range(len(n) - 1 - i):
            if n[j] > n[j + 1]:
                n[j], n[j + 1] = n[j + 1], n[j]
    return n
```

While `my_bubble_sort()` is **much** faster on processing lists that are already sorted, `some_other_bubble_sort()` is almost three times faster (= takes 35% of the time) compared to `my_bubble_sort()` on actually random, unsorted lists.

I'm not sure why that is. Can anyone help me understand?

It can't be the additional checks against `switched` that make my implementation that much slower, can it?

**[Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/YHgv03KW)**

I also found that my version seems to be fairly close to **[the one taught at this MIT lecture](https://youtu.be/6LOwPhPDwVc?t=14m54s)**.

Which one is generally preferable? Are they both valid implementations of `bubble sort`? Or is either of the two technically another sorting algorithm?

And which one would be preferable, generally speaking?

Comment: Algorithms other than Bubblesort are "preferable" by most metrics people care about. People don't spend a lot of time wondering which of two slightly different but suboptimal in both theory and practice algorithms to use.

Answer (score 3):

From your pastebin, here is the first place you go wrong:

```
unsorted1 = unsorted2 = [randint(1, 99) for _ in range(count)][:]
```

Here you assign `unsorted1` and `unsorted2` to point to the same list. So when you call `some_other_bubble_sort` on `unsorted2`, it is in fact no longer shuffled! It is sorted.

The solution is to first assign `unsorted1` and then `unsorted2` to a copy:

```
unsorted1 = [randint(1, 99) for _ in range(count)]
unsorted2 = unsorted1[:]
```

That makes your algorithm only slightly less than twice as slow. That can be explained simply by the fact your implementation does a lot more stuff. In Python the little things add up, like setting `switched` to `True` every iteration.